# Системный разделитель целой и дробной части?

Tags: java

Как вытащить системный разделить целой и дробной части, который установлен у пользователя? (запятая или точка).

Answer (score 3):

Копипаста [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713166/decimal-separator-in-numberformat):

```
DecimalFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char sep = symbols.getDecimalSeparator();
```